# User-defined tuple-based data constructors

Tags: haskell, types, tuples, sml, cons

Me trying to grok *The Little MLer* again. TLMLer has this SML code

```
datatype a pizza = Bottom | Topping of (a * (a pizza))
datatype fish = Anchovy | Lox | Tuna
```

which I've translated as

```
data PizzaSh a = CrustSh | ToppingSh a (PizzaSh a)
data FishPSh = AnchovyPSh | LoxPSh | TunaPSh
```

and then an alternative closer to TLMLer perhaps

```
data PizzaSh2 a = CrustSh2 | ToppingSh2 (a, PizzaSh2 a)
```

And from each I create a pizza

```
fpizza1 = ToppingSh AnchovyPSh (ToppingSh TunaPSh (ToppingSh LoxPSh CrustSh))
fpizza2 = ToppingSh2 (AnchovyPSh, ToppingSh2 (LoxPSh, ToppingSh2 (TunaPSh, CrustSh2)))
```

respectively, which are of type `PizzaSh FishPSh` and `PizzaSh2 FishPSh` respectively.

But the second version (which is arguably the closer to the original ML version) seems "offbeat." It's as if I'm creating a 2-tuple when I "cons" toppings together where the second member recursively expands . May I assume the parametric data constructor "function" of `PizzaSh2` doesn't literally build a tuple, it's just borrowing the tuple as a cons strategy, correct? Which is preferable in Haskell, `PizzaSh` or `PizzaSh2`? As I understand, a tuple (cartesian product) data type will have a single constructor, e.g., `data Point a b = Pt a b`, not the disjoint union of ored-together (|) constructors. In SML the "*" indicates product, i.e., tuple, but, again, is this just a "tuple-like thing," i.e., it's just a tuple-looking way to cons a pizza together?

Comment: Yes, the `PizzaSh2` constructor _does_ literally contain a tuple.

Comment: Thanks. Still trying to sort out the difference between a data constructor function and a normal function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Haskell, we prefer this style:

```
data PizzaSh a = CrustSh | ToppingSh a (PizzaSh a)
```

There is no need in Haskell to use a tuple there, since a data constructor like `ToppingSh` can take multiple arguments.

Using an additional pair as in

```
data PizzaSh2 a = CrustSh2 | ToppingSh2 (a, PizzaSh2 a)
```

creates a type which is almost isomorphic to the previous one, but is more cumbersome to handle since it requires to use more parentheses. E.g.

```
foo (ToppingSh x y)
-- vs
foo (ToppingSh2 (x, y))

bar :: PizzaSh a -> ...
bar (ToppingSh x y) = ....
-- vs
bar (ToppingSh2 (x, y)) = ...
```

Further, the type is indeed only *almost* isomorphic. When using an additional pair, because of laziness, we have one more value which can be represented in the type: we have a correpondence

```
ToppingSh x y     <->    ToppingSh2 (x, y)
```

which breaks down in the case

```
???               <->    ToppingSh2 undefined
```

That is, `ToppinggSh2` can be applied to a non-terminating (or otherwise exceptional), pair-valued expression, and that constructs a value which can not be represented using `ToppingSh`.

Operationally, to achieve that GHC uses a double indirection (roughly pointer-to-pointer, or thunk-returning-pair-of-thunks), which further slows down the code. Hence, it's also a bad choice from a performance point of view, if one cares about such micro-optimizations.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention strict fields with `UNPACK` pragmas for those situations where you really want to do that and get a precise isomorphism with the same representation.

Comment: @dfeuer Is there any advantage to do that in this case? Writing `data T = T {-# UNPACK -#} ! (X,Y)` looks much worse than the alternative, IMO. I'm not sure why I would recommend that.

Comment: I think it's sometimes helpful. For example, imagine `data Pt = Pt !Int !Int; data Segment = Segment {-# UNPACK #-} !Pt {-# UNPACK #-} !Pt`. This communicates very clearly that a segment is made of two points, and which `Int` is paired with which, while maintaining a compact segment representation. It also makes it very easy (though not free) to separate the points if necessary or to build a segment from points.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the Haskell side, it absolutely is nesting a `(,)` constructor inside the `ToppingSh` constructor. It would violate Haskell's non-strict semantics to not do the nesting you requested. If the nesting was removed, you'd be unable to distinguish between `undefined :: PizzaSh2 ()` and `ToppingSh undefined :: PizzaSh2 ()`. And yes, most of the time, that isn't what you want. `PizzaSh` is the much more natural formulation in Haskell unless you have a particular need to be able to introduce another bottom into the evaluation process.

I can't address what's going on behind the scenes in any particular ML implementation. Though I can say that with strict evaluation semantics, there isn't a behavioral difference to observe, meaning compilers are free to use a wider variety of approaches.